# How can I turn rows that have the same id to one longer row? Im not exactly looking to pivot in this scenario

Tags: python, pandas

for example my dataframe looks like this below

```
id    |   answer      |     reason
1     |    yes        |      possible fraud
1     |    maybe      |      scam
2     |    no         |      no evidence

how can I turn it into something like this below?

id    |    answer_1  |     reason_1     | answer_2    |reason_2
1     |    yes       | possible fraud   |   maybe     | possible fraud
2     |    no        |    no_evidence   |             |
```

Comment: Check with the Q10 in the link

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your edit. This **is** a pivot, so why are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: Should `reason_2` be 'scam' in your expected output?

Comment: How can I get the column names to enumerate properly when I pivot and yes reason_2 should be scam